# Asp.net vs Html5 vs xml vs xhtml

Tags: asp.net, xml, html, xhtml

Please help me pick witch language I should use for continuing to create webpages. I am an intermediate at html and would like to know the pros of cons of using asp.net, xml, xhtml and html. The websites I will be designing will have (hopefully) graphics. It would contain what is going on the the selected city at that given moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML and HTML5 are standards for the HTML language, in the XML family. You will be typing most of the same tags more or less regardless of which standard of HTML you choose. If you are making websites you should be writing with HTML5 in mind, because that is the most current standard (although not fully supported in all browsers).

ASP .NET is a framework from Microsoft that you have the option of using alongside HTML5 code. It runs on the backend of a web server.

I recommend reading more about the different languages used on the web.